# sream to bytes[] return null. stream is an image

Tags: c#, image, stream, byte

Converting an image `Stream` to `byre[]` always returns null.
Here is the codes :

```
    ...

    Stream Stream = responce.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Stream);
    string reader_str = reader.ReadToEnd();

    byte[] bytes = ReadFully(Stream); //I don't know why bytes is NULL

    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
             int read;
             while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
             {
                  ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
             }
             return ms.ToArray();
         }
     }
```

Stream is a png image!
How can i save that image like below?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Stream.CopyTo(ms);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms); //Parameter is not valid ERROR
img.Save(image_path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: You've already read your stream to the end via `reader.ReadToEnd();`.  You'll need to `Seek()`.  Any reason for `reader_str`?

Comment: Sure, let me remove it & see the result!

Comment: Thanks dude. Solved! Put it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already read your stream to the **end** via `reader.ReadToEnd()`;. You'll need to `Seek()` to the **beginning** prior to reading from the stream again.

Any reason for `reader_str`?